# How to set complicated condition in typorm insert

Tags: javascript, typescript, typeorm

when I try to insert data by referring certain condition. `if shopId = "shopA"` then I would like to insert `shopdetail`. to achieve this, I set following business logic. but it is a little complicated.

Are there smarter way to achieve this?

```
request = {
 Id:"test",
 shopId:"shopA",
 element:"testElement"
}


if(request.shopId = "shopA") {
PricingPattern = {
 Id:request.Id,
 element:request.element,
 shopdetail:{
   shopId:request.shopId
  }
 }
} else {
PricingPattern = {
 Id:request.Id,
 element:request.element
 }
}


await getRepository(PricingPattern)
                .save([this.pricingPatternInfo])
```

if someone has opinion will you please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

TypeORM Subscribers?
https://orkhan.gitbook.io/typeorm/docs/listeners-and-subscribers#beforeinsert

```
@Entity()
export class PricingPattern {
   @BeforeInsert()
   onlySaveShopADetail() {
      if (this.shopdetail.shopId !== 'shopA') {
         delete this.shopdetail;
      }
   }

}
```

then usage below:

```
request = {
 Id:"test",
 shopId:"shopA",
 element:"testElement"
}

const a: Partial<PricingPattern> = {
 Id:request.Id,
 element:request.element,
 shopdetail:{
   shopId:request.shopId
  }
 }

await getRepository(PricingPattern)
                .save([this.pricingPatternInfo])
```